# Use invocable method on the MergeCaseController, error that i will not be able to use the invocable method on a constructor. thank you

Tags: apex, controller, invocable-method, constructor

I am trying to use the invocable method on `Public MergeCaseController(ApexPages.StandardsetController controller)` so that i can call this from a flow.. But i am having issues doing so,

---

```
    public without sharing class MergeCaseController {
    
      
      private static final integer LIMIT_CASES = 25;
        
          public class wrapperCase {
            public Case caso {get;set;}
            public boolean atribuir {get;set;}
            private list< EmailMessage > email{get;set;}
            Public list< Attachment > anexo{get;set;}
                    
          }
        
    
        public list<wrapperCase> lstCase {get;set;}
        //private list<Case> lstSearchCase;
        private map<id,Case> lMapCase;
        public String localizarid {get;set;}
        public String caseId {get;set;}
        public String msg {get;set;}
        @TestVisible private Case casoController;
        private ApexPages.StandardsetController lController;
      
       
        @InvocableMethod(label='Merge')
        Public MergeCaseController(ApexPages.StandardsetController controller)
          
      {
           
        lController = controller;
        casoController = (Case) controller.getRecord();
        String lIdPage = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Refid');
          
          
    
        if(lIdPage != null)
        {   
     
           list<Case> lstIdpage = [SELECT CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE id =:lIdPage];
           if ( !lstIdpage.isEmpty())
           {
           caseId = lstIdpage.get(0).CaseNumber;
           localizarid = caseId;
           }
        }
        InternalLocalizarCase( true, controller.getSelected() );
      }
       private void carregar( boolean aFlag )
        {   
    map <id, list< EmailMessage > > mapEmail = new map <id, list< EmailMessage> >();
      
    for(EmailMessage email: [SELECT id,Subject, BccAddress, MessageDate, ParentId, TextBody, Status, 
       CcAddress,  ToAddress ,FromAddress, Incoming
       FROM EmailMessage WHERE ParentId =: lMapCase.keyset()]){
       
      list< EmailMessage > lListEmail = mapEmail.get( email.ParentId );
      if ( lListEmail == null )
      {
          lListEmail = new list< EmailMessage >();
          mapEmail.put( email.ParentId, lListEmail );
      }
      lListEmail.add(email);
    }  
    
    lstCase = new list<wrapperCase>(); 
    
    for(id lcasoId: mapEmail.keySet())
    {
     
     wrapperCase lwp = new  wrapperCase();
     lwp.caso = lMapCase.get(lcasoId);  
     lwp.atribuir = aFlag;
     lwp.email = mapEmail.get(lcasoId);
     lstCase.add(lwp);
        
    }
    
    if ( lstCase.isEmpty() )
    {
        adicionaErro('Selected cases do not meet the criteria for merge.');
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to use the invocable method on Public MergeCaseController(ApexPages.StandardsetController controller) so that i can call this from a flow.. But i am having issues doing so, any help will be much appreciated thank you

Comment: The annotation `@InvocableMethod` is used on methods, not constructors. You can pass the required ID as a parameter to the Invocable method and use it to implement further logic in the method. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at some of the code of these invocable actions. They show common patterns: https://unofficialsf.com/flow-actions/  (generally there's a link to source code at the bottom of each piece of documentation)

basically, set up a new apex class called something like MergeCase. Give it a method like 'execute' and put the invocable method on that. Then inside that execute method, call your merge code.